# Processing order of SynchronizationContext.Post

Tags: .net, multithreading

I use the `SynchronizationContext` to invoke methods from my background thread on the UI thread. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2473073/342594) which asks for the difference of `Send` and `Post`. I understand the answer and would call `Send` whenever I need the result of the called method to proceed and I would call `Post` whenever I don't care for the result.

My question is: **Can I make any assumption on the order in which the `Post`ed delegates are called?** For example I would `Post` messages that could be displayed in a log window on the UI thread. But if the `Post`ed delegates don't get processed in the order they are invoked, the message log would display the message out of order, too.

I could solve that by `Send`ing the messages, but do I really need to worry about that?

Comment: [This](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2014/10/12/159645.aspx) would be a good read for you. Are you using WinForms or WPF? I think this would be implementation specific to the `SynchronizationContext` you're using.

Comment: Thanks @YuvalItzchakov. The article explains it quite well. I use WinForms by the way. The article describes a situation where messages get out of order (when posting a sending command). At least in my code I will prevent the situation. But I can not make any assumptions on what the per Post invoked method does. Maybe it's bad API design, but I don't feel responsible for that. So far I would consider my question solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can depending on the app model you are using, which will inform which `SynchronizationContext` you us. Different implementations have different behaviours, which is well illustrated in table (Figure 4) in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx).

So desktop UI based `SynchronizationContext` implementations will guarantee ordered execution of delegates, and for others it is not guaranteed.